# Tern: Synchronizing script resources with tern server

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jboss, ide, tern

In JBoss Devstudio, I am getting this new "error" with Tern: `Synchronizing script resources with tern server`.  It's not really an error, but it's a process that occurs every single time I click in a JavaScript file.  It's just spinning and freezes up the entire IDE.  This has never happened to me before, and I was working on the project yesterday without any issues.

Does anyone know what the hell this is?  There isn't really anything on Google except one post that says to upgrade.

Comment: I have this problem also. I wonder about Help->Installation Details, and then UNINSTALL the `JBoss Tools Java Standard Tools Tern.java Adapter`.   Will that fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

JBoss Devstudio integrates [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java) for JavaScript support. I think your problem is because that you have a lot of JavaScript files in your project (inside `node_modules` or `bower_components`) and tern.java tries to analyze your all JavaScript files, and it takes time.

In your case, you need to **exclude folders** like node_modules and to do that you must use a version of tern.java >= [1.0.0](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/New-and-Noteworthy-1.0.0) which support **include/exclusion pattern path**.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work! I tried to set the exclusion path to `**/*.js` but it still fires up the Synchronize when I modify a JS file.  How do I tell it to exclude **everything**?

Answer (score 3):

To deal with this problem, open your workspace and drop the folder, like `E:\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\tern.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.embed.win32.win32.x86_64`, the `node.exe` in it is the point.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by simply eliminating the built in js files from path.

1. I removed this from validations '**/node_modules/*,**/bower_components/*'. (If it even didn't resolve)Go to Properties of the project > JavaScript > Include Path > Validation

OR

2. Go to Properties of the project > JavaScript > Include Path > Source and remove the whole project. Click on "Add Folder" and give the required path for your JS. Like projectname/src/pages.